# Elements of each list into an array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list say

```
A = [[[1], [2]],
     [[3], [4]],
     [[5], [6]],
     [[7], [8]],
     [[9], [10]],
     [[11], [12]]]
```

Now I want to convert into an array something like this

```
A = [[1,3,5,7,9,11],[2,4,6,8,10,12]]
```

elements of every list into an array

```
My real data looks something like this,
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[2.9077100703958676, 2.907707020607246, 2.907696129398862, 2.9076922793200826], [1.5831895878032682, 1.5831799549447967, 1.5421635176438928, 1.54216257550671]]
    [[], [3.6722596549808784, 3.6722526678432876, 3.671068320950512, 3.6710584810218814, 1.4814967342403382, 1.4814744077628512, 1.158833238469524, 1.158820971788903]]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], [11.161297964771585]]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], [1.7247699149091442, 1.7247456715167526, 1.3559139927513728, 1.3559021903808808]]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], [53.3587073998281, 53.3587073998281]]
    [[], []]
    [[], []]
    [[], [73.51669471981023]]
    [[], [12.93677609502523, 12.936752858061059]]
    [[], [20.935136118658637]]
```

This is what I got when I print the variable

Is there any way we can do this ?

Comment: 1. `A` isn't a valid data structure as shown. 2. This isn't a code-writing service. That said, if `A` is actually a list of lists of lists, you could do `map(lambda t: sum(t, []), zip(*A))`.

Comment: ...swing and a miss. Commas, please. Also, if you need a 3D list, you might give `numpy` a try.

Comment: I donno what you called this, wait i'll edit my question

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is my data I dono what you call this.

Comment: So it's actually **not** a list? `type` will tell you what it is.

Comment: in my IDE it shows only list

Comment: What you've shown isn't a valid list, as it is lacking commas. If `type(A) is list`, then I really don't know what you've done. Please give a [mcve] that actually shows what you're dealing with and, more importantly, **how *you've* tried to fix it so far**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is a vector but in type it shows only list

Comment: *"Please give a [mcve] that actually shows what you're dealing with and, more importantly, **how* you've *tried to fix it so far**."*

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your definition of A is invalid.

Assuming you meant `A = [[1,2],[3,4],...]`, you can do this:

```
[[x[0][0] for x in A ], [x[1][0] for x in A]]
```

Comment: In that case it's even easier - `map(list, zip(*A))`.

Comment: No it is a list of lists of list

Comment: I adjusted for that, but looking at your real data, it looks like the arrays may be empty as well sometimes, which you'll have to account for.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. For your real data it will throw an index out of range error.

Comment: no in my real data if I print A[0] am getting all first column elements so i think it's nothing to do with 2D representation

Comment: Mine is like a vector

Comment: Since both your example data and your "real data" are not valid python, I really can't do anything with that. That's why my answer starts with: "Assuming you meant...", and as such my answer is not incorrect. It just makes an assumption about your question that may be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = [[[1], [2]],[[3], [4]],[[5], [6]],[[7], [8]],[[9], [10]],[[11], [12]]] # ouch.
>>> [list([item[0] for item in tuple]) for tuple in zip(*A)]
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

---

Edit: Original answer assuming a 2D list below:

```
>>> A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
>>> zip(*A)
[(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12)]
>>> [list(tuple) for tuple in zip(*A)]
[[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

or, if it's

Comment: If `A = [[[1], [2]],[[3], [4]],[[5], [6]],[[7], [8]],[[9], [10]],[[11], [12]]]`, is it work correctly?

Comment: @SakibAhammed that's the sort of thing you could trivially find out, surely?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I do understand actually what you want to say?

Comment: @SakibAhammed despite the question mark, I'm not sure that's a question. My point is that you could have pasted the code into an interpreter and tested for any value of `A` you wanted, rather than asking whether *"it work correctly"*.